# Importing multiple Excel sheets from a selectable location

Tags: excel, vba, import, merge

I am trying to make a button in Excel to trigger a screen for a user to select a folder location, and add all of its Excel files into work sheets.

```
Sub Getsheets()
Path = GetFolder("N:\", "Select an Input Folder")
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String, fldSt As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = fldSt
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

This is what I have so far, if I don't incorporate the `getfolder` function, I can retrive all Excel files in a designated folder, but once I put the function in, nothing happens. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print Path` after the call to GetFolder and see what you get.  It will print out to the Immediate pane in the VB editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filedialog does return a path without the trailing "\" (platform dependant).
You need to append the trailing "\" manually before searching for "*.xlsm"

So the 3rd line of code would be :

```
Filename = Dir(Path & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xlsm")
```

EDIT 
There are other references to Path where the PathSeparator must be added.

Actually, it is better programatically to take a reference on the workbook when you open it. Also, better to declare variables (use "Option Explicit" on 1st line of the module to enforce this).

Here is your code, updated to match the above thoughts:

```
Sub Getsheets()
    Dim Path As String, Filename As String, Sheet As Worksheet, wkBook As Workbook
    Path = GetFolder("N:\", "Select an Input Folder") & Application.PathSeparator
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wkBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        For Each Sheet In wkBook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wkBook.Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

I tested this on a folder with 5 .xlsm files in it ; it worked fine.

Comment: Hey d-stroyer, thank you for your answer. I get an error message with "file name in the folder" cannot be found. Check your spelling, or try a different path. Then Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. Do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: I tested and didn't see these errors. But I saw that the answer was incomplete (several references to Path in your code). So I edited the answer. Please check the updated version of Getsheets and tell me if it works for you. For me it works.